# How to select a value in second dropdown based on value selected in first dropdown? both values are coming from the database

Tags: javascript, jsp, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a page for writing Book Review. On that page, I have a dynamic dropdown where the values for Title and Author of a book are coming from the database. I need to make sure if user selects Java as book title, the author should be selected as Kathy sierra. How to ensure that?

The code is follows:

This is on bookreview.jsp

```
  <select name="jumpMenu_group" size="1" id="jumpMenu_group">
        <option value=""></option>

        <% for(int i=0; i<beanList.size(); i++)
    {
        %>
        <option value="<%=beanList.get(i).getTitle() 
               %>"><%=beanList.get(i).getTitle() %></option>
        <%} %>
</select>

 <select name="jumpMenu_group2" size="1" id="jumpMenu_group">
         <option value=""></option>
        <% for(int i=0; i<beanList.size(); i++)
    {
        %>
        <option value="<%=beanList.get(i).getAuthor()
            %>"><%=beanList.get(i).getAuthor() %></option>
        <%} %>


        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to get the selected value and set the appropriate value in the second drop-down. You also have repeating ID's (on the `select` elements) -- **ID's must be unique**

Give your second dropdown a different ID (for this example, I'm just using jumpMenu_group2)

```
document.getElementById("jumpMenu_group").onchange = function() {
    var selected = this.value; //currently selected value;
    var author = document.getElementById("jumpMenu_group2"); //second select element;

    //Do value comparison here
    if (selected == "Java")
        author.value = "Kathy Sierra"; //these values must exist in the dropdown, if they dont, add them dynamically
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So change your jsp code to next

```
 <select name="jumpMenu_group" size="1" id="jumpMenu_group">
    <option value=""></option>

    <% for(int i=0; i<beanList.size(); i++)
{
    %>
    <option data-author="<%=beanList.get(i).getAuthor()" value="<%=beanList.get(i).getTitle() 
           %>"><%=beanList.get(i).getTitle() %></option>
    <%} %>
   </select>

   <select name="jumpMenu_group2" size="1" id="jumpMenu_group2">
     <option value=""></option>
    <% for(int i=0; i<beanList.size(); i++)
{
    %>
    <option value="<%=beanList.get(i).getAuthor()
        %>"><%=beanList.get(i).getAuthor() %></option>
    <%} %>


    </select>
```

I used data-attribute in option(data-author) to know author and title from first select

Add javascript to your page (my code depends on jQuery library)

```
$("#jumpMenu_group").on("change", function(){
 var val = $(this).attr("data-author");
 // now we know author
 $("#jumpMenu_group2").val(val);
});
```

Also my advice for you:

1. Dont use one id for two elements, because ID means uniqal name of element
2. [read this about id and class](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_idclass.htm)